# Print Total Number of Different Words (case sensitive) from a file

Tags: java, fileinputstream

**Edit after reviewing Tormod's answer and implementing his advice.

As the title states I'm attempting to print the total number of different words after receiving a file name from command line input. I receive the following message after attempting to compile the program:

Note: Project.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Here is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        HashSet lib = new HashSet<>();

        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            int count = 0;
            while(sc.hasNext()) {
                sc.next();
                count++;
            }
        System.out.println("The total number of word in the file is: " + count);
        }

    while (s.hasNext()) {

        String data = s.nextLine();
        String[] pieces = data.split("\\s+");

        for (int count = 0; count < pieces.length; count++)
        {
        if(!lib.contains(pieces[count])) {
            lib.add(pieces[count]);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print(lib.size());
}
}
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO! Try and make program output stand out - one mechanism would be *blockquote* (prepend `> `).) What is the (runtime) "history" of `fis` when `countWord()` is invoked?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand the question.

Comment: `count` is never incremented because you are checking that `s` must be equal to `word`. `word` is always the empty string.

Comment: At some point in time, the `Object` passed to `countWord()` as `FileInputStream fis` will have been instantiated. What, if anything, happened to/with that object in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement it using a HashSet Add all the words, and read out the size. If you want to make it case insensitive just manipulate all the words to uppercase or something like that. this uses some memory but...

one problem you got with the algorithm is that you do only have one "words". it only holds the words at the same line. so you only count same words at the same line.

**HashSet** stores strings by their hash value, and thus stores one word only one time.

construction: HashSet lib = new HashSet<>();

inside the loop: if(!lib.contains(word)){lib.add(word);}

check the word count: lib.size()

Comment: I'm not too familiar with HashSet. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I edited my original question and code incorporating your advice. When I try to compile, I receive the following: Note: Project.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: in the constructor: HashSet<String> lib = new HashSet<>(); this will declare a typed HashSet not a raw type HashSet. and if you do not use late java versions you must type: HashSet<String>  lib = new HashSet<String>();

Comment: Thank you. It is now functioning properly. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String s : words) {
    if(s.equals(word))
        count++;
}
```

You are comparing the words to an empty String, since it's a word it's always gonna be false.

Like Tormod said, the best would be to store the words in a HashSet, as it won't keep duplicates. Then just read out its size.